# Choosing X elements out of Y elements - chance to see k elements from Y in n trials

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The following question arose for me this morning regarding an upcoming test that will have a pool of **Y** questions, with **X** questions being chosen for the actual test. Every single participant out of **n** participants will have this procedure done for him, so that every test tries to be a bit different.

What is the probability to see **k** questions of pool **Y** in **n** attempts (**n** participants)? Or say, I want to see **z** percent of the questions from **Y**, how many participants (**n**) do I need (with a reasonable probability **k**)?
I hope this question is clear.

Thanks

Comment: First try to do it with some constants and then try generalizing. Might help. Also, [Bernoulli Trials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial)

Comment: honestly, this is really just a real-life-I-am-interested question by me; I do not have any connection to the mathematical profession (apart from some semesters in physics long ago, which still keeps my interest in maths/physics). I was looking again into Bernoulli trials because of another question I had regarding 1/k in k attempts (which I found mysel) but I wasn't able to extrapolate that for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\PM}{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\IQ}{\mathbf{1}_{Q_i}}$
So $Y$ is the total number of questions. Each exam contains $X$ question. So $X\leq Y$. Let us assume that each question will be chosen with equal probability and each question is different. Let us also assume that each exam is made independent of the others. It is actually like sampling without replacement for each exam seperately. Let $\mathbf{1}_{Q_i}$ the indicator function that tells if question $i$ is in the exams. The probability that question $i$ is not in the exams is equal to:
\begin{align}
\PM(\IQ = 0 ) = \prod_{j=1}^n(1-\PM(\text{question } i \text{ is in the exam of student } j))
\end{align}
Furthermore $\PM(\text{question } i \text{ is in the exam of student } j) = \frac{X}{Y}$ (why?) so:
\begin{align}
\PM(\IQ = 0 )= \left(1-\frac{X}{Y}\right)^n
\end{align}
We are interested in $\sum_{i=1}^n\IQ$, because that is the indicator that tells us how many different questions are in the exam. Since $\IQ$ is bernoulli distributed with parameter $p=1-\left(1-\frac{X}{Y}\right)^n$ then is the sum is binomially distributed with parameter $(n,p)$ hence:
\begin{align}
\PM(\text{ See } k \text{ questions in the exam } ) &= \PM\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\IQ = k \right) \\
&= \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} \\
&=   \binom{n}{k} \left( 1-\left(1-\frac{X}{Y}\right)^n\right)^k \left(1-\frac{X}{Y}\right)^{n(n-k)}
\end{align}
I hope this helps and that I understood your question well.

Comment: This is awesome! But I have some problems re-arranging that equation, so that I could get n as the value of interest. Do I have to say P=1 (to see a set amount of questions) and re-arrange, so that n=...? I have problems doing that, but I might try that later again when I have got some spare time. Say I want to know how many participants I need, so that I get to see 70% of the questions.

Comment: That is in generally not an easy problem since you want to find the inverse function of the last expression that I have there. It will not work in general. Such function cannot exist for every value you will think of...However you can let a computer calculate it for the value for which it is closest to, say 70%. Did this help?

Comment: That helped, thanks!